# Mock не виртуального метода чужого класса

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, testng, moq

Не могу протестировать метод из за того что класс `Row` является составной частью чужой библиотеки.

Внутри тестируемого метода вызывается не виртуальный метод `Remove()` объекта класса `Row`.

Я пытался его "замокать":

```
var mockRow = new Mock<Row>();
mockRow.Setup( r => r.Remove() );
Row normalRow = mockRow.Object;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
System.NotSupportedException : 
Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: r => r.Remove()
```

Если бы я вызывал только метод  `Remove()` объекта `Row` я бы мог создать интерфейс `IRow` с сигнатурой `void Remove()` внутри и создавал бы объекты `Row` используя этот интерфейс. Но в других ветках алгоритма я у объекта `Row` вызываю разные родные его методы, а писать все возможные вызовы этого объекта я думаю не самая элегантная идея.

Есть ли способ как то решить проблему?

На всякий случай привожу часть метода который тестирую:

```
public virtual bool Delete( string[] idArray )
{
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = _rwh.GetWorksheetPart();
    IEnumerable<Row> rows = _rwh.GetRows( worksheetPart );
    List<string> deletedRowsId = new List<string>();
    bool setOffsetIndexesRow = false;

    if ( rows != null && idArray != null )
    {
        foreach ( string idDeleteRow in idArray )
        {
            foreach ( Row row in rows )
            {
                if ( setOffsetIndexesRow )
                {
                    SetOffsetInRowsAndCells( row );
                }
                if ( _rwh.IdCompare( idDeleteRow, row ) )
                {
                    row.Remove(); // <---------------------------
                    setOffsetIndexesRow = true;
                    deletedRowsId.Add( idDeleteRow );
                }
            }
            setOffsetIndexesRow = false;
        }
    } else {
        //....
    }
//.....
}
```

Так же код теста(может я делаю что-то не так):

```
[Fact]
public void Delete_Return_True_When_Deleted_Row_Equal_Recived_Ids()
{
    var mockRow = new Mock<Row>();
    mockRow.Setup( r => r.Remove() );
    Row normalRow = mockRow.Object;

    IEnumerable<Row> rowlist = new List<Row>( new Row[] { normalRow } );

    var mockRowWriterHelper = Mock.Of<RoWriterHandler>(
        rwh => rwh.GetRows( It.IsAny<WorksheetPart>() ) == rowlist &&
                rwh.IdCompare( It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Row>() ) == true
        );

    var rowDeleter = new RowDeleter( string.Empty, string.Empty, null, mockRowWriterHelper );

    string[] idArray = new string[] { "test" };
    //
    var resultStatus = rowDeleter.Delete( idArray );

    //
    Assert.True( resultStatus );
}
```

Comment: Зачем тестировать чужую библиотеку?

Comment: Да я не чужую тестирую я просто хочу что бы чужая возвращала хоть что нибудь что бы протестировать свою логику метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что в юнит текстах нет смысла тестить чужой код. Если вам надо как то переварить из Row во что то с виртуальными методами, закрывайте чужой код интерфейсом и пишите декоратор/адаптер, мокайте интерфейс

```
public class Row
{
    public void Remove()
    {       
    }
}

public interface IRow
{
    void Remove();
}

public class RowAdapter : IRow
{
    private Row _inner;
    public RowAdapter (Row inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public virtual void Remove()
    {
        _inner.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Тоесть если я правильно понимаю мне надо перекрывать все чужие методы своими интерфейсами даже если их много? Другого способа нет?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov в идеале ваши юнит тесты вообще не должны зависеть от стороннего кода. Чтобы ваш код не зависел от него, желательно его закрывать абстракциями. Методы вам надо мокать только те, что вы вызываете в своем коде. То есть если у стороннего класса 200 методов, но вы пользуете только 1, то его только и надо перекрывать.

Comment: если я вас правильно понял: когда я использую чужие библиотеки то под каждую пишу адаптер и интерфейс в котором описываю только те методы которые использую? На прямую использовать библиотеки нельзя? А если я использую какой-то тип из сторонней библиотеки и этот тип передаю в библиотеку-же, что там происходит какие вызовы внутри я незнаю, мне в этом случае надо описывать весь публичный интерфейс?

Comment: Если эти библиотеки участвуют в тестах, то да. Это нужно, чтобы эти библиотеки из тестов убрать. Но это рекомендация, а не абсолютное правило.

Comment: Если вы используете библиотечный тип и передаете его же туда, в библиотеку, то это наверное в рамках какой то операции происходит, которая закрыта интерфейсом